# Sending large file in websocket before timeout

Tags: ruby, faye, em-websocket

I'm using Faye and EventMachine to open a socket to another server. The server times out if it doesn't detect activity. How do I send the file (binary encoded) so the server doesn't time out?

Here's what I have:

```
media_path = "/path/to/media/file"

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(uri)

  ws.on :open do |event|
    puts "Opening socket"
    ws.send(File.read(media_path))
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    puts "Recieving message"
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    ws = nil
    EM.stop
  end
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [send your file in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962134/ruby-read-file-in-batches). Something like that:

```
ws.on :open do |event|
  puts "Opening socket"
  File.open('filename','r') do |f|
    ws.send(f.gets)
  end
end
```

You solve another problem this way: you wouldn't place your whole file in RAM + you'll send it faster. You can read about [nodejs streams](http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/), there is a similar principle of operation.

Comment: gets might get you inconsistent data sizes. Consider using `f.read 65_536` - 64KB (2**16) is a decent package size, but you should probably change in accordance with your circumstances.

Comment: P.S. Your sending only the first line. Consider adding `until f.eof?`

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly of a duplicate for [How to send binary file over Web Sockets with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425796/how-to-send-binary-file-over-web-sockets-with-rails/33442162#33442162) Although this question did come first...

Please see my answer to that question for another option that won't block your application while you send your file.