# How to send binary file over Web Sockets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, websocket, faye

I have a Rails application where users upload Audio files. I want to send them to a third party server, and I need to connect to the external server using Web sockets, so, I need my Rails application to be a websocket client.

I'm trying to figure out how to properly set that up. I'm not committed to any gem just yet, but the ['faye-websocket'](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) gem looks promising. I even found a similar answer in "[Sending large file in websocket before timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976055/sending-large-file-in-websocket-before-timeout)", however, using that code doesn't work for me.

Here is an example of my code:

```
@message = Array.new
EM.run {
    ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new("wss://example_url.com")

    ws.on :open do |event|
      File.open('path/to/audio_file.wav','rb') do |f|
        ws.send(f.gets)
      end
    end

    ws.on :message do |event|
      @message << [event.data]
    end

    ws.on :close do |event|
      ws = nil
      EM.stop
    end
}
```

When I use that, I get an error from the recipient server:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

This makes sense, because the I don't believe it's properly formatted for faye-websocket. Their [documentation](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#websocket-api) says:

> send(message) accepts either a String or an Array of byte-sized
>   integers and sends a text or binary message over the connection to the
>   other peer; binary data must be encoded as an Array.

I'm not sure how to accomplish that. How do I load binary into an array of integers with Ruby?

I tried modifying the `send` command to use the `bytes` method:

```
File.open('path/to/audio_file.wav','rb') do |f|
    ws.send(f.gets.bytes)
end
```

But now I receive this error:

```
Stream was 19 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes
```

I know my file is 286KB, so something is wrong here. I get confused as to when to use `File.read` vs `File.open` vs. `File.new`.

Also, maybe this gem isn't the best for sending binary data. Does anyone have success sending binary files in Rails with websockets?

**Update:** I did find a way to get this working, but it is terrible for memory. For other people that want to load small files, you can simply `File.binread` and the `unpack` method:

```
ws.on :open do |event|
  f = File.binread 'path/to/audio_file.wav'
  ws.send(f.unpack('C*'))
end
```

However, if I use that same code on a mere 100MB file, the server runs out of memory. It depletes the entire available 1.5GB on my test server! Does anyone know how to do this is a memory safe manner?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on it:

```
# do only once when initializing Rails:
require 'iodine/client'
Iodine.force_start!

# this sets the callbacks.
# on_message is always required by Iodine.
options = {}
options[:on_message] = Proc.new do |data|
   # this will never get called
   puts "incoming data ignored? for:\n#{data}"
end
options[:on_open] = Proc.new do
   # believe it or not - this variable belongs to the websocket connection.
   @started_upload = true
   # set a task to send the file,
   # so the on_open initialization doesn't block incoming messages.
   Iodine.run do
      # read the file and write to the websocket.
      File.open('filename','r') do |f|
         buffer = String.new # recycle the String's allocated memory
         write f.read(65_536, buffer) until f.eof?
         @started_upload = :done
      end
      # close the connection
      close
   end
end
options[:on_close] = Proc.new do |data|
   # can we notify the user that the file was uploaded?
   if @started_upload == :done
        # we did it :-)
   else
        # what happened?
   end
end

# will not wait for a connection:
Iodine::Http.ws_connect "wss://example_url.com", options
# OR
# will wait for a connection, raising errors if failed.
Iodine::Http::WebsocketClient.connect "wss://example_url.com", options
```

It's only fair to mention that I'm [Iodine's](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) author, which I wrote for use in [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) (a RESTful Websocket real time application framework you can use stand alone or within Rails)... I'm super biased ;-)

I would avoid the `gets` because it's size could include the whole file or a single byte, depending on the location of the next End Of Line (EOL) marker... `read` gives you better control over each chunk's size.