# Parse large stdin ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance

I need to write script for parse large input data (30GB). I need extract all numbers from stdin text and output it by order desc.

Example of usage: 
`cat text_file_30gb.txt | script`

Now I use for parse:

```
numbers = []
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  numbers += line.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
end
numbers.uniq!.sort!.reverse!
```

But I tried to pass text from 60MB file to script and it parsed it for 50 min

Are the way for speed up script?

UPD.  Profiling result:

```
 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 95.42   5080.882  4848.293     0.000   232.588        1   IO#each_line
 3.33    169.246   169.246     0.000     0.000   378419   String#scan
 0.26     15.148    13.443     0.000     1.705   746927   <Class::Time>#now
 0.18      9.310     9.310     0.000     0.000   378422   Array#uniq!
 0.15     14.446     7.435     0.000     7.011   378423   Array#map
 0.14      7.011     7.011     0.000     0.000  8327249   String#to_i
 0.10      5.179     5.179     0.000     0.000   378228   Array#sort!
 0.03      1.508     1.508     0.000     0.000   339416   String#%
 0.03      1.454     1.454     0.000     0.000   509124   Symbol#to_s
 0.02      0.993     0.993     0.000     0.000    48488   IO#write
 0.02      1.593     0.945     0.000     0.649   742077   Numeric#quo
 0.01      0.649     0.649     0.000     0.000   742077   Fixnum#fdiv
 0.01      0.619     0.619     0.000     0.000   509124   String#intern
 0.01      0.459     0.459     0.000     0.000   315172   Fixnum#to_s
 0.01      0.453     0.453     0.000     0.000   746927   Fixnum#+
 0.01      0.383     0.383     0.000     0.000    72732   Array#reject
 0.01     16.100     0.307     0.000    15.793    96976  *Enumerable#inject
 0.00     15.793     0.207     0.000    15.585   150322  *Array#each
 ...
```

Comment: Well, you probably can't hold all 30 GB in memory all at once, so you'll need to sort them on disk. Also, it might be faster if you didn't use ruby for this (instead use C or something).

Comment: @Adrian I agree with you absolutely but I need do it on Ruby for exam :(

Comment: Did you try something like `IO.foreach('text_file_30gb.txt').lazy.grep(/\d+/)`. Also refer to this it might help: http://blog.honeybadger.io/using-lazy-enumerators-to-work-with-large-files-in-ruby/

Comment: @Cyzanfar I have no filename in script, I have stdin only. Or u suggest write stdin to file before parsing?
Tnx for url, I will try this method

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not sure about that...

Comment: Do you have the sample file?

Comment: If `numbers.uniq!` is far smaller than `numbers` (i.e., lots of dups), you might make `numbers` a set rather than an array. That would reduce memory requirements but I doubt that it would speed the calculations. What is your rough estimate of the counts of numbers (not digits) and unique numbers in the file?

Comment: @nhmtanveer it could be absolutely different files with random text. I test script with 64mb log file

Comment: @CarySwoveland final array must contains >= 10_000 unique items

Comment: I was hoping for `<=`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland oh, of course, sorry :-D

Comment: If it's less than a few million that says locating the numbers in the text is the bottleneck, as `uniq!`, `sort!` and `reverse` would take very little time.

Comment: Read by chunk - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962134/ruby-read-file-in-batches

Comment: I think `numbers += ...` is taking way too much, as it allocates new array per `+=` call. However, use `<<` instead. That will add value to the existing array instance. 

I am adding a quick example based on your current one, which takes up 11 to 12 minutes just with few tweaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the excellent problem.

I couldn't dig for a long time. However, this is what I can see as a quick fix to reduce 50 mins mark to 11 mins. At least 4.5 times faster.

```
require 'ruby-prof'

def profile(&block)
  RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(RubyProf.profile(&block)).print($stdout)
end

numbers = []

profile do
  $stdin.each_line do |line|
    line.scan(/\d+/) {|digit| numbers << digit.to_i }
  end

  numbers.uniq!.sort!.reverse!
end
```

The reason is pretty simple. As you can see `+=` on array allocates new array instead of pushing new values to the existing reference. A quick fix is using `<<` instead. A big win that along cut the whole lag.

Still, there are some significant glitches if you juggle with larger file set. I don't have anything top of my head.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank u so much